# Ctrl+Shift+M apparently intercepted by Chromium, does not get through to Jupyter

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, chrome, jupyter

Working in a Jupyter Notebook, I often want to press Ctrl+Shift+M to "Merge Cell Below". However, there seems to be a clash of keyboard shortcuts and it brings up the user profile popup of Chromium. How can I suppress Chromium from intercepting this shortcut?

Versions used:

- Ubuntu 23.04 (happens to be running within a UTM virtual machine, on
  Apple M2 hardware, under macOS Sonoma 14.0, however this should be
  immaterial to the question)
- Chromium Version 118.0.5993.70 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)
- Jupyter Version: 7.0.4